# Kidney Problems in Older Dog (Potentially CKD)

Tags: dogs, diseases, urination

I have a 13lb. (5.9kg) female schnauzer/poodle mix who is currently 12 years old.

On March 16, she was given a dental chew. Later that night, she threw up the chew and we found a lot of urination throughout the house. After that, she appeared OK.

Mar 17, we found more urine that she produced during the night.

Mar 18, she urinated in her sleep while laying next to me; something she has never done. I also noticed that this urine was colorless and oderless. She has also been drinking 3 to 4 times more water than normal.

Mar 19, thinking it might be a UTI, we took her to the vet and she was diagnosed with Chronic Kidney Disease (CKD). Her lab test results are:

| Test | Result | Range | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Neutrophil | 85.0 | 42.0-84.0 | % |
| Eosinophil | 0.2 | 1.0-18.0 | % |
| Hemoglobin (HGB) | 20.6 | 1.0-18.0 | g/dL |
| Hematocrit (HCT) | 57.92 | 37.0-55.0 | % |
| MCH | 26.4 | 19.5-24.5 | pg |
| BUN | 49.0 !!! | 7.0-27.0 | mg/dL |
| Calcium | 2.5 | 7.9-12.0 | mg/dL |
| Creatinine | 2.5 !!! | 0.5-1.8 | mg/dL |

The results of all other tests are within normal range.

The vet put her on a special diet (Royal Canin KD) and stated to return in a month for retest.

Mar 19 through today Mar 22, her drinking and urination continue to be excessive. I'm guessing she drinks 3-4 cups (0.7-0.9 L) per day and urinates just as much. Her urine also remains clear and oderless.

Other than the excessive drinking and urination, she has no other symptoms. She is just as playful and energetic as she has always been, not lethargic, no obvious pain or discomfort.

I know the prognosis for CKD is not good. I'm taking her to another vet on Mar 26 for a second opinion and more tests.

My questions are:

1. How likely is it truly CKD, vs acute kidney disease or even Pyelonephritis?
2. Any medications to help with kidney function?
3. Any supplements to help with kidney function (Aventi KP and/or Epakitin)?
4. What can we do about excessive urination (other than frequent trips outside and diapers at night)?

She is not my dog, she is my daughter and I want to do everything I can to help her. Any input is welcome and will be discussed with a vet.

Thank you!

Comment: I am no vet, so I do not know a wide range of illnesses. But from my personal experience drinking and urinating a lot rings a bell. Please test if there is sugar in the urine. This are symptomes for diabetics. If the body is not able to break down the sugar in the blood to energy, the sugar works like intoxination. The body tries to get rid of it via the urine. Regularly there should be no sugar in the urine.

Comment: @Allerleirauh That is a good point you made, I'll discuss it with her vet. Thank you!

Comment: Honestly, there's not much you can do about the urination - it is how it is. We bulk bought urine eliminator at the end of our late dog's life when he couldn't control it.  Dealing with a human parent with the same issue, I'd also say that to keep an eye on *other* things changing - my dad's CKD meds triggered high potassium levels which was not good. Other than that - with our dog, he was diagonosed around that age, and with a good vet he went on to the ripe old age of 16.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Both my wife and I would be happy if she made it to 15 or 16 years. It's been a week since the new diet and her thirst/urination has gone down a slight amount, just enough where frequent trips outside and a diaper at night keeps things under control. Thank you so much for your time in answering, it means a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Good news... I took her to another vet and did a complete blood workup in addition to some other advanced tests (like SDMA). The results of these tests show her kidney values returning to normal. Because of this, the doctor diagnosed her with a kidney injury and expects her to make a good recovery.

To answer my questions...

1. You never know until you get a second opinion.
2. Yes there are medications, but none needed in this case.
3. Yes there are supplements, but bloodwork will show if they'll be helpful (e.g. it's not a good idea to use phosphate binders if phosphate levels are normal or low).
4. There are things that can be done about polyurea depending upon the cause. The vet will determine the best course of action.

Thank you everyone for giving your time to read and comment.